# To pass a delegate/command as a parameter to another command in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, delegates

I have a user control 'A' that has another user control 'B' as its child. The usecase scenario being, when the user clicks a button on 'A', it should *request* 'B' to process some information (typically relating to the state of 'B') and get the result, which will then be used in some calculation in 'A'.

Now, I am using MVVM pattern. The viewmodel of 'A' does not have any reference to either the UI of A or B. I am exactly looking for this: When a user cliks a button on the UI of 'A', I need to call a command in 'B', by passing a delegate in the viewmodel of 'A' as a parameter to that command. This way, when the command in 'B' processes information, it can *then* call the callback function passed from 'A'.

Now, the delegate is parameter-less. Once the command in usercontrol 'B' processes some information, it updates *its state*. This state is a dependency property which will be binded to a property in the viewmodel of 'A'.

Is there a way to achieve something like this?

I have a working solution currently. But I want to improvise the code and make it better. This is my current temporary workaround to this problem:

When the user clicks a button in 'A', I am having an Event Handler in 'A' (xaml.cs). In the event handler, as I have the reference of 'B', I am checking if the command in 'B' can be executed, and then call it. Then, I check if command (in viewmodel of 'A') can be executed, and then call it.

If my question was not descriptive enough, here is a code sample to support it:

**XAML of 'A':**

```
<bNameSpace:B x:Name="BObject" DepenPropertyInB="{Binding PropInA, Mode=OneWayToSource}"/>
....
<telerik:RadButton Content="Process" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="30" Width="80" Grid.Column="2" Click="ProcessButton_Click" />
```

**XAML.cs of A:**

```
private void ProcessButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (BObject.StateDataRequestedCommand.CanExecute(""))
        BObject.StateDataRequestedCommand.Execute("");

    if(ViewModel.ProcessInfoRequestedCommand.CanExecute(""))
        ViewModel.ProcessInfoRequestedCommand.Execute("");
}
```

**ViewModel of A:**

```
private void OnProcessInfoRequestedCommand(string anyValue)
{
    // read the value of PropInA and do some processing
}
```

**ViewModel of B:**

```
private void OnStateDataRequestedCommand(string anyValue)
{
    // Bases on B's state do some calc and update DepenPropertyInB
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll come back and add more detail to this later, but here's basically what I think needs to happen.

The click should have a `DelegateCommand` type implementation, that contains a reference to the view models of both A and B.  You need some kind of "conductor" class that is instantiating the view models, and which can pass the appropriate references into the command object.

---

So, clearly the command belongs in the View Model for A, *but*, it needs a reference to B.  So set up the command class with that in mind:

```
public MyCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly ViewModelA _a, ViewModelB _b;

    public MyCommand(ViewModelA a, ViewModelB b)
    {
        _a = a;
        _b = b;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object arg)
    {
        // can-execute logic here
    }

    public void Execute(object arg)
    {
        _b.StateDataRequestedCommand.Execute("");
        _a.ProcessInfoRequestedCommand.Execute("");
    }
}
```

Now, but an instance of *MyCommand* into A's View Model...

```
public MyCommand StateRequestedCommand { get; set; }
```

And bind to it as normal...

```
<telerik:RadButton Command="{Binding StateRequestedCommand}" />
```

Now, the challenge is to instantiate this class within A's View Model somehow.  I normally use NInject to inject external dependencies into classes, but there are different ways to do it.  Either way, it has to happen at a higher level than ViewModelA itself, since it doesn't have a reference to ViewModelB.  That could be in the App_Startup logic, or in IoC (eg, NInject) bindings, or in a View Model "Locator", if that's what you're using.

Comment: I am interested in knowing more about this solution, so please come back and elaborate this.

Comment: @Shankar I updated my answer.  Maybe a bit vague still, but I hope it helps in some way.

Comment: Thank you dbaseman, this is good solution, and using Prism, the View models can be injected easily.

Answer (score 2):

Each command require CommandParameter and you use it but send "" instead of a real parameter.
A parameter can be anytype because it decleared as object. So you can send any object as a parameter to any command.

```
class CommandA : ICommand
{
  void Execute(object param)
  {
    var commandB = param as CommandB;
    if(commandB != null)
    {
      commandB.Execute((int a) => {
          // continue your code here
        });
    }
  }

  bool CanExecute(object param)
  {
    return param is CommandB;
  }
}

class CommandB : ICommand
{
  void Execute(object param)
  {
    var action = param as Action<int>;
    if(action != null)
    {
      action(10);
    }
  }
}

class MVA
{
  CommandA CommandA{get;}
  CommandB CommandB{get;}
}
```

XAML:

```
<Control x:Name="A" Command="{Binding CommandA}" CommandParameter="{Binding Command, ElementName="B"}">
  <Control x:Name="B" Command="{Binding CommandB} />
</Control>
```

Comment: Can you provide some example that you have tried to achieve this?

Comment: I haven't tried this out yet. Will let you know when I do. Thank you for your effort to resolve this.